# Стерилизация ввода в contenteditable div

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, задалась на досуге одним довольно интересным вопросом. Хотела бы сделать так что бы в div(contenteditable=true) можно было вставлять тег img, но не более. Т.к в дальнейшем все будет заноситься в базу данных! Стандартные функции в php экранируют все теги. Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему для одного тега ? заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему для одного тега ?

как вариант, внимательней читать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) :)

```
$text = strip_tags($text, '<img>');
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я как понимаю эта функция будет игнорировать все теги кроме тега img,да ?

Comment: Она удалит все теги, кроме img.